# JsonResponse doesn't return data in template

Tags: jquery, python, json, django

I have django 1.7 and I made a view where I want to receive information sent by jquery 2.1.1

I can receive the information in the view and print it, but when I use `JsonResponse` to send the JSON to my function in the template, and a `console.log` to view the JSON, nothing happens.

views.py

```
def filtro(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        carrera = Event.objects.filter(category__name = request.GET['id'])
        reponse = JsonResponse({'name' : carrera.name, 'age' : carrera.summary})
        return HttpResponse(response.content)
    else:
        return ('/')
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^filtro/$', 'apps.eventos.views.filtro', name="filtro"),
```

eventos.html

```
$('.list li a').on('click', Filtrar);
  function Filtrar(){
    var id = $(this).text()
    $.ajax({
      data : {'id' : id},
      url : '/filtro/',
      type : 'get',  
      success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
      }
    });

  };
```

When someone clicks on any `a` tag, I want to show the information by JSON from my models.

Comment: `carrera ` seems to be a filtered queryset. How are you able to get `name` and `summary` from this?

Comment: @AKS yes it is a queryset, I iterate with a for, and thats another thing, I want to send all the objects in that model in the response with json, Can I do that too?

Answer (score 1):

Prevent the default click event

```
$('.list li a').on('click', Filtrar);
  function Filtrar(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).text()
    $.ajax({
      data : {'id' : id},
      url : '/filtro/',
      type : 'get',  
      success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
      }
    });

  };
```

return a json response

```
return JsonResponse({'name' : carrera.name, 'age' : carrera.summary})
```

Comment: Great I will try this, but if I want to send all the objects I got in that model that I filtered, this will work too? thank you

Comment: have you looked in the console for any errors, how does the xhr request look like?

Comment: Error 500, and i didnt look the xhr but i will now.

Comment: Where can it be my mistake in the view?

Comment: open /filtro/?id=5 in a browser and you can see the errors

Answer (score 0):

I don't know python but for you jquery ajax call i think 
 `data : {'id' : '\"'+ id + '\"'},` instead of `data : {'id' : id},` would solve your issue.

Because you are sending a string so you need to add it inside quotations sign.

Comment: why concatenate the id ??

Comment: I can receive the string in the view, text() works fine, It sends, but the thing is when I want to send back to the function in the template, I dont see a thing, even in the console, I will try the preventdefault as @madalinivascu said.. and I let you know if it works.  Thank you